# angular2 - pipe error

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I have this `PipeGalleryFilter.ts`:

```
import { Pipe,Injectable,PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'galleryfilter',
    pure: false
})
@Injectable()
export class PipeGalleryFilter implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
        return items.filter(item => item.type.indexOf(args[0].type) !== -1);
    }
}///@@
```

then I add it to my `Gallery`:

**html**

```
<masonry-brick class="brick50" *ngFor="let brick of bricks | galleryfilter: gallery_args">
  <img src="{{brick.img}}" alt="">
</masonry-brick>
```

**ts**

```
gallery_args = {type: 'magazine'};

bricks = [
     {title: 'Brick 1',img:"assets/img/img003.jpg",type: "magazine"},
     {title: 'Brick 2',img:"assets/img/img004.jpg",type: "magazine"},
     {title: 'Brick 3',img:"assets/img/img005.jpg",type: "newspaper"},
     {title: 'Brick 4',img:"assets/img/img003.jpg",type: "newspaper"},
     {title: 'Brick 5',img:"assets/img/img004.jpg",type: "newspaper"},
     {title: 'Brick 6',img:"assets/img/img005.jpg",type: "newspaper"},
     {title: 'Brick 1',img:"assets/img/img003.jpg",type: "movies"},
     {title: 'Brick 2',img:"assets/img/img004.jpg",type: "commercials"}, 
     {title: 'Brick 3',img:"assets/img/img005.jpg",type: "commercials"},
     {title: 'Brick 4',img:"assets/img/img003.jpg",type: "commercials"},
     {title: 'Brick 5',img:"assets/img/img004.jpg",type: "lifestyle"},
     {title: 'Brick 6',img:"assets/img/img005.jpg",type: "lifestyle"}
   ];
```

But I keep getting:

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./Gallery class Gallery - inline template:22:39
>   caused by: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

I kind of suspect it has something to do with the line `return items.filter(item => item.type.indexOf(args[0].type) !== -1);`, but I am not sure how to get it right.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `gallery_args` is an object (as you showed in your question), not an `array`, so `gallery_args[0]` of course will be undefined.

Modify your `transform` function to:

```
transform(items: any[], args: any): any { // Note that the type of args should be any or {}
  return items.filter(item => item.type.indexOf(args.type) !== -1);
}
```